# Displaying row index while looping using ui:repeat in JSF

Tags: jsf, facelets

I am using ui:repeat tag and I have set varstatus="current".I try to display the row index using the below command, but nothing is getting displayed.

```
   <h:outputText value="#{current.index}"/>
```

I would like to display the row index.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was introduced in [Facelets 2.x](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/ui/repeat.html). Given the fact that it doesn't work, you're using [Facelets 1.x](http://facelets.java.net/nonav/docs/dev/docbook.html#template-repeat).

Facelets 2.x is not standalone available. It is embedded in JSF 2.x. If you can, upgrade to JSF 2.x. If you can't, then you've either to wrap the model in a custom model which holds the index as well, or to grab `<c:forEach>` instead if your view markup allows it (it's a view build time tag, not a view render time tag), or to grab [Tomahawk's `<t:dataList>`](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk/tagdoc/t_dataList.html) instead which has a `rowIndexVar` attribute for this purpose.

---

**Update** as per the comments, you turn out to be using RichFaces. In that case, you can also use the [`<rich:dataList>`](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/rich_dataList.html) or [`<a4j:repeat>`](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/a4j_repeat.html) which offers both a `rowKeyVar` attribute:

```
<a4j:repeat value="#{bean.items}" var="item" rowKeyVar="index">
    <p>#{index} #{item}</p>
</a4j:repeat>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot BalusC. Is it possible to get the index in rich:dataList?

Comment: Oh, you're using RichFaces? It's 3.3.x I assume? Yes, definitely you can use it instead, just set `rowKeyVar="index"` and use `#{index}`. The `<a4j:repeat>` also supports this attribute and may be a better substitute to `<ui:repeat>`.

Comment: It is richfaces 3.3.x.Thanks :) - I owe you big time! I used dataList but I am able to see bullets. I presume I must make necessary style class changes for me to suppress the bullets.